# How can I know the view is in touch state in Android

Tags: android, touch-event

How can I know the view is in touch state.
If more than one touch points on one view,How can I catch the event of the last up touch point.
Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [onTouchEvent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) on your `View`. `ACTION_DOWN` will be given when the first "pointer" is placed. From then on, you will get `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` or `ACTION_POINTER_UP` as subsequent fingers are pressed down and then released.  Then, when the last pointer/finger is released, your View will get `ACTION_UP`.  This is spelled out clearly in the [MotionEvent docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Something like this might be what you're looking for, just subclass whatever `View` you are working with.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        isTouching = true;
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        isTouching = false;

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I think the code is only used in single touch. If more than one pointers,one of them is up and the other is not up,but it will get MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event.

Comment: Is the `View` you are working with a subclass of `ViewGroup`? I think it's a bit more complicated if you're working with a `View` that has children.

Comment: It is OK now.If multiple touch pointers.the first down pointer catch 'ACTION_DOWN',and others catch 'ACTION_POINTER_DOWN'.The last down pointer catch 'ACTION_UP',and others catch 'ACTION_POINTER_UP'